# Magento blank page

Tags: php, magento

```
[20-Feb-2015 17:45:02 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Varien_Autoload' not found in /home/vzvutpbd/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 53
```

[20-Feb-2015 17:46:32 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  include_once(Mage/Core/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/vzvutpbd/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 49
[20-Feb-2015 17:46:32 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  include_once(): Failed opening 'Mage/Core/functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/php4/lib/php:/usr/local/php4/lib/php:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/vzvutpbd/php') in /home/vzvutpbd/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 49

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that all files listed are there & have appropriate read permissions.

[Magento - Wiki - Resetting File Permissions](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions)

This should resolve your issues, granted the files are indeed there.

Comment: Hi moose thanks for the reply, i tried to use magento cleanup tool:

Comment: ----------------------- CLEANUP START -------------------------

*************** SETTING PERMISSIONS ***************
Setting all folder permissions to 755
Setting all file permissions to 644
Setting pear permissions to 550

****************** CLEARING CACHE ******************
Clearing var/cache
Clearing var/session

************** CHECKING FOR EXTENSIONS ***********
-= WARNING =- Overrides or extensions exist in the app/code/local folder
-= WARNING =- Overrides or extensions exist in the app/code/community folder

------------------- CLEANUP COMPLETED in:1.2600 seconds ------------------

Comment: @Luca Puggioni - still no changes to your circumstance? What changes were made to cause this behaviour? You're going to need to add a bit more detail.

Comment: Hi moose, i didnt nothing on this server for months and months.. I also tried to install a fresh copy of magento with Installatron, from my cPanel and i've the same problem ! Blank page.. My provider told me a genial solution: we can reset your cpanel if you want.. WHAT ?